# Getting multiple rows of a single employee while using Subqueries in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I am writing a query to get the benefits details of employees. I need to fetch the deduction amount of different plans and options. For the deduction amount there is one field in a table. I am fetching that field multiple times for different plans and options. I did this using subqueries. But my query is returning multiple rows of a single employee and in multiple rows its displaying the amount. I want all deduction amounts in a single row for a single employee.

This is how I have written the query:-

```
select papf.person_number, csv.salary_amount, (select bprv.rt_val from ben_prtt_rt_val bprv,
     ben_opt_f bof, 
     ben_pl_f bpf, 
     ben_pl_typ_f bpt where bprv.prtt_enrt_rslt_id=bper.prtt_enrt_rslt_id and bper.pl_typ_id=bpt.pl_typ_id and bpf.pl_typ_id=bpt.pl_typ_id and bper.pl_id=bpf.pl_id and bper.opt_id=bof.opt_id and bpt.name ='abcd' and bpf.name='abcd' and bof.name='Participant'
and (sysdate between bof.effective_start_Date and  bof.effective_end_Date)  
    and  (sysdate between bpt.effective_start_Date and  bpt.effective_end_Date)
    and (sysdate between bpf.effective_start_Date and  bpf.effective_end_Date)) as "abcd Amount",
(select bprv1.rt_val from ben_prtt_rt_val bprv1,ben_opt_f bof1, 
     ben_pl_f bpf1, 
     ben_pl_typ_f bpt1 where bprv1.prtt_enrt_rslt_id=bper.prtt_enrt_rslt_id and bper.pl_typ_id=bpt1.pl_typ_id and bpf1.pl_typ_id=bpt1.pl_typ_id and bper.opt_id=bof1.opt_id and bper.pl_id=bpf1.pl_id and bpt1.name ='efgh' and bpf1.name='efgh' and bof1.name='Participant'
and (sysdate between bof1.effective_start_Date and  bof1.effective_end_Date)  
    and  (sysdate between bpt1.effective_start_Date and  bpt1.effective_end_Date)
    and (sysdate between bpf1.effective_start_Date and  bpf1.effective_end_Date)) as "efgh Amount",
(select bprv2.rt_val from ben_prtt_rt_val bprv2,ben_opt_f bof2, 
     ben_pl_f bpf2, 
     ben_pl_typ_f bpt2 where bprv2.prtt_enrt_rslt_id=bper.prtt_enrt_rslt_id and bper.pl_typ_id=bpt2.pl_typ_id and bpf2.pl_typ_id=bpt2.pl_typ_id and bper.opt_id=bof2.opt_id and bper.pl_id=bpf2.pl_id and bpt2.name ='ijkl' and bpf2.name='ijkl' and bof2.name='Participant'
and (sysdate between bof2.effective_start_Date and  bof2.effective_end_Date)  
    and  (sysdate between bpt2.effective_start_Date and  bpt2.effective_end_Date)
    and (sysdate between bpf2.effective_start_Date and  bpf2.effective_end_Date)) as "ijkl Amount"
from
     ben_prtt_enrt_rslt bper,
     per_all_people_f papf  ,
     cmp_salary csv
where 
    bper.assignment_id=csv.assignment_id    
    and bper.person_id=papf.person_id    
    and  (sysdate between papf.effective_start_Date and  papf.effective_end_Date) 
    AND CSV.DATE_TO=(SELECT MAX(CSV1.DATE_TO) FROM CMP_SALARY CSV1 WHERE CSV.ASSIGNMENT_ID=CSV1.ASSIGNMENT_ID)
```

I want the result like this:-

```
Employee     Salary    abcd_amt    efgh_amt     ijkl_amt 
1234              10000       200         300         400
```

But using the query I am getting result like this:-

```
Employee  Salary  abcd_amt         efgh_amt           ijkl_amt
1234       10000    200             
1234       10000                       300         
1234       10000                                         400
```

and also duplicate rows.

Please help me out. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: can you add your table layouts and some sample data? I think this can be done easily with joins but don't really have a good insight into what your tables look like

Comment: It seems to me that you should group your data based on the employee. Thus you will get a single row per employee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add group by and Max in your query like this :

```
select papf.person_number as Employee, csv.salary_amount as Salary
max(-query of abcd_amt-) as abcd Amount, 
max(-query of efgh_amt-)as efgh Amount, 
max(-query of ijkl_amt-) as abcd Amount
from  --tables names
where -- where condition
group by papf.person_number, csv.salary_amount;
```

Comment: It's not letting me group by papf.person_number with max function.